# Matching SQL table header value with another table column value

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 Database table like below there Table_1 & Table_2. Table_1 column index is match with id value of table_2. Name values of Table_2 will be column header at result of query.

```
Table_1
______________________________________________
| date      |city_1 | city_2 | ... | city_100 |
|-----------|-------|-------------------------|
| 20.02.2013|   4   |   34   | ... |   222    |
| 21.02.2013|   3   |   10   | ... |    33    |
|    ...    |  ...  |   ...  | ... |   ...    |
|_____________________________________________|


  Table_2
___________________
|  id   |   name  |
|-------|---------|
|   1   | newyork |
|   2   | london  |
|  ...  |   ...   |
|  100  | istanbul|
|_________________|
```

Expected result is below

```
  __________________________________________________________
  |  date     |  newyork   |   london   |  ...  |  istanbul |
  |-----------|------------|------------|-------|-----------|
  | 20.02.2013|     4      |     34     |  ...  |    222    |
  | 21.02.2013|     3      |     10     |  ...  |     33    |
  |   ...     |    ...     |    ...     |  ...  |    ...    |
  |___________|____________|____________|_______|___________|
```

What is the SQL query to get result above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a solution like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME, ' as ', Table_2.Name), COLUMN_NAME))
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  LEFT JOIN Table_2
  ON Table_2.ID = SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_NAME, '_', -1)
WHERE table_name = 'Table_1' INTO @sql;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM Table_1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce2b7/1).
This code will extract all columns names of Table_1, and will try to join the name of the columns with the IDs in Table_2. If there's a match, I'm returning the name of the column with an alias, like this:

```
city_1 AS newyour
```

and using GROUP_CONCAT the variable @sql will contain all the columns like this:

```
date,city_1 as newyork,city_2 as london,city_100 as istanbul
```

I'm then concatenating `'SELECT '` + the column names with alias + `' FROM Table_1'`, and executing the resulting query.